# My Wordpress theme not translate

Tags: wordpress, translate

i have a problem.I install `stitch` theme on wordpress and i want to translate this theme from english to `persian`.I create `fa_IR.mo` and `fa_IR.po` and replace in languages directory of stitch theme.Now add this bottom code to functions.php and header.php :

```
<?php load_theme_textdomain( 'stitch',get_template_directory().'/languages/fa_IR.mo'); ?>
```

but my theme still english!!!!Please help me.Where i wrong!!
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Codestyling Localization - https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/.

You can check if your po/mo files are in proper location, scan your template/plugins for new words for translation, etc. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the stich theme have already included a language file configuration, so you don't have to. BTW, your code should go into functions.php, and the `fa_IR.mo` part is not needed

All you have to do is, in your wp-config.php, look for this line

```
 define( 'WPLANG', '' );
```

And change it to

```
define( 'WPLANG', 'fa_IR' );
```

This will set your language to persian

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/translating-your-theme--wp-25014). It helped me on my theme.

Comment: Tanks alot my friend.